# jQuery, Can't get value of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code, I can get the object but not the value.  How can I get the value of the `.cups` textbox?  Thanks.

HTML:

```
<tr id="20">

      <td class="description">CHEESE,FONTINA</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="cups" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="breakfast"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="lunch"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="dinner"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="snack"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="favorites"></td>
      <td><label class="addFood"><input type="button" class="input_text_custom input_button" value="Add"></label></td>

</tr>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.addFood').click(function () {

        var tr = $(this).parents('tr');

        var foodId = tr.attr('id');  // works
        var servings = tr.children('.cups');  // returns [object Object]
        var servings = tr.children('.cups').val();  // returns undefined
        alert(servings);

    });

});
```

Comment: Dom ID's must start with a letter.

Comment: @Jleagle that was true before HTML5

Comment: @Jleagle — That restriction was lifted in [html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<input>` is a grandchild of `<tr>`, not a child, so it won't be selected by [`.children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and you get a jQuery object which has no members when you try it (this is akin to an empty array).

Use [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead, that operates on descendants.

Answer (score 3):

I always find that it is best to be as verbose as you can with jQuery selectors. Especially when it comes to classes as there can be more than one element or *types* of elements that could be matched. Id's are unique so `tr#20` is overkill (IMO).

I would use something like this -

```
var cupsValue = $("#20 input.cups").val();
```

If you still want to use a derivative of your code, I would also suggest that you use `closest()` and not `parents()` (unless there is something I'm missing from your markup). You are only looking for one parent object, the closest `tr` that is a parent of the current element.